# Capturing screenshot of windowed OpenGL window in AutoIt?

Tags: windows, opengl, scripting, automation, autoit

For my graphics class, I need to match an OpenGL sample output in a pixel-perfect way.

I figured it would be cool if I could spawn the sample, send it some input, then take a screenshot of the exact OpenGL area, do the same for mine, and then just compare those screenshots. I also figured something like AutoIT would be the easiest way to do something like this.

I know that I can use the screencapture function, but I'm unsure of how to get the exact coordinates and size of the OpenGL area of the window (not the title bar/surrounding window stuff).

If anybody could help me out that would be awesome. 
Or if anybody can think of an easier solution than AutoIt, and can point me in the right direction, that'd be great too.

EDIT: I also don't have access to the source code of the sample output program.

Comment: "For my graphics class, I need to match an OpenGL sample output in a pixel-perfect way." Note that OpenGL implementations do not produce pixel-perfect results. You should talk to whomever is in charge of your class and inform them of this fact.

Comment: We're actually using GLUT with only a SetPixel function exposed, writing software rasterizers. So I feel like that would produce the same output on the same machine.

Comment: You need a screen grabbing utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoIt is a pretty good tool for this job. I think you already found the _ScreenCapture in the help file, it has parameters for: X left, Y top, X right and Y bottom coordinates. However, the _ScreenCapture function stores to a file. I've made a library where you can capture part of the screen, or a window, and save this to memory. Then you can get the pixel colors from the memory and compare them to your existing pixels. You can find it here: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/63318-get-or-read-pixel-from-memory-udf-pixelgetcolor-au3/

The part of a window which does not include the titlebar and the borders is called the 'client area'. You can get the width and the height of the client area with the WinGetClientSize. Alternatively, you can use ControlGetPos on the OpenGL control to get the X and Y relative to the window, and the width and height of the OpenGL control. Combined with WinGetPos you should be able to calculate the values you need for _ScreenCapture. You should be able to find out a good approach if you use the "AutoIt window info" tool.

Finally, a simple and short solution which gives you little control, but might be just what you need, is the PixelChecksum function. Once you have the coordinates of the OpenGL part, you can use PixelChecksum and get a value corresponding to the pixels of the screen (a checksum of the pixels). You can then compare this value to a pre-recorded value to tell whether the pixels on the screen are exactly the same. Check the Autoit help file of PixelChecksum for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture data from an OpenGL buffer, here is how you can do it with legacy OpenGL (version 1.2 or so)

```
glFinish();
glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
glReadPixels(ox, oy, w, h, mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
```

where:

- `ox` and `oy` are origin x and y
- `w` and `h` are width and height
- `mode` is the mode, like GL_BGR if you want to save to BMP
- `img` is a pointer to `unsigned int *` to copy the image to

You can search for `glReadPixels` on the internet and see the reference for more information.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is I don't have access to the source code of the sample program, so I have to try and capture the exact output of a program I can't edit.